# Android: Navigation Drawer NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I am using code from the developer website (http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) to install a navigation drawer, however, I am getting a NullPointerException in this method:

```
/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Here is the error

```
04-14 20:51:39.720: D/dalvikvm(826): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 93K, 6% free 3119K/3284K, paused 95ms, total 96ms
04-14 20:51:39.970: I/Choreographer(826): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-14 20:51:40.360: I/Choreographer(826): Skipped 256 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-14 20:51:40.440: D/gralloc_goldfish(826): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-14 20:51:40.730: D/AndroidRuntime(826): Shutting down VM
04-14 20:51:40.730: W/dalvikvm(826): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2ac7ba8)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 826
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onPrepareOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:139)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.Activity.onPreparePanel(Activity.java:2556)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:464)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-14 20:51:40.740: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the rest of the main activity

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_options);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
         // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
//        switch(item.getItemId()) {
//        case R.id.action_websearch:
//            // create intent to perform web search for this planet
//            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
//            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
//            // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
//            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
//                startActivity(intent);
//            } else {
//                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//            }
//            return true;
//        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
//        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

**menu xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: What do you have in line 139 in this method? (See *MainActivity.java:139* in your logcat)

Comment: Line 139 is the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method

Comment: @Libin I figured it out by looking at my menu xml file. Thank you for that, I'll post the original menu xml file and select your answer as the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your menu.xml has only one time with id= action_settings. You should add another menu item for search.

example: 
You can use searchView

```
<item
 android:id="@+id/action_search"
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
 android:title="@string/action_search"
 app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
 app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
```